# Google Analytics Campaign Tracking Issues

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, tracking, event-tracking

A client of mine is having some issues with regards to tracking campaigns in Google Analytics that I was hoping one of you can advise me on.

They have recently sent out an email with the Google Analytics campaign information in the links back to the site from a button in the email (link created with the URL builder).

As well as the Google Analytics information they also send their own parameter for tracking using a bespoke system of theirs. In the end the url that visitors would go to after clicking the button in the email was something along these lines:

http://www.domain.com/pagename/?bespokecampaign=lead_gen/email/email_btn/boxcampaign&utm_source=email_pure&utm_medium=email&utm_term=email_btn&utm_campaign=boxcampaign

Looking at Acquisitions in the Google Analytics report I can see in the past this page has been viewed and has the correct Source/Medium set as email_pure/email.

However, there was a lead gen form that was filled out on the site after landing on this particular page that sends an event action that the form was filled out. When trying to view the campaign information for these events I do not see any information regarding the Source / Medium for that event being the correct information from the URL.

The Salesforce model in place to receive these leads took the referrer URL correctly, containing the Google Analytics parameters, but there was no record in Analytics to suggest one of the form events had the Source/Medium of email_pure/email.

Does anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this and potential fixes?

Comment: Could you give some more info about where did seek for the information? What reports you've checked? Did you use segments/filters? Maybe problem is with proper report setup? Especially, that you see proper data in Acquisition report and hopefully you've recorded events properly (do you see any lead events in Events Summary report?)

Comment: In Behavior > Events I can see all the form submit events and if I put the Secondary dimenion as Source/Medium I can see some of these displayed as "google/organic" "google/cpc" and other referrals, but none with the "email_pure/email" as it should show if the Original Referral data collected in Salesforce is correct.

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea why you do not see leads with proper medium/source info. But what I suggest is to try two things. First, try to set a goal based on this lead event. Than, maybe you will see number of leads acquired per campaign/medium/source in Acquisition report. Second, you may try to define a segment either session or user based, to filter out sessions/users which came from this particular medium/source. Than just check if you will see anything in Events report.